# In Oozie, like Actions have retry options, are there similar options at the Workflow level?

Tags: oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

We have an Oozie Workflow with some Spark, Hive, and SSH actions. Occasionally the workflow fails due to some singular issues. And pretty much always the failed instance succeeds upon re-running it. However, I couldn't find any automatic retry options at the workflow or coordinator level.

I did see that Actions have retry options like number of retry attempts and after how long to retry. It'll help as a workaround for now - but it got me wondering if workflows really don't have any such options?

The Workflows & Coordinators are created and maintained using Hue (3.12) editor - not directly through the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no such option in Oozie. However, Oozie's workflow definition language allows you to create loops using [subworkflow actions](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-shorten-your-oozie-workflow-definitions/) and decision nodes.